# How can "go to website" button lead to a blank homepage in pyrocms?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

After installation of pyrocms, when I click the "go to website" button, I would like the homepage to be completely blank. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: which version are you using? any in the logs? system/cms/logs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure! Open up index.php end insert this on the first line:

```
exit;
```

Comment: ahahaha you made my day!

Comment: @ Christian Giupponi ... I tried it ... it worked but 1 more thing happened, the admin page of my blog has disappeared too. I want it to be intact. Just the homepage to be blank so that I can work on it as on a clean slate.

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi I'm gonna cherish this accept :)

Comment: This will make every page blank, not just he homepage as OP states.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is not a joke:

Why don't you just go in the admin panel and in the settings module you close the site?
When users go to the site, and they're no an admin user, they will see an error message that you can easly edit to show a blank page.

If you add the exit as suggested you in the other comment you will kill also the Admin section

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a blank homepage, then go to Content > Pages, click "Add Page", use "Home" as the title, /home as the URL, go to Options and check the "Is default (home) page?" option, add some dummy text to the content then click Save & Exit.

Next, add a blank file at `addons/shared_addons/thems/your-theme/views/layouts/home.html` (or where ever your theme is) and you will have a blank homepage.